# Accessing an object's workflow state in collective.easytemplate

Tags: plone

I would like to use collective.easytemplate to generate templated emails (for content rules).  However, I am not sure if it can output an objects workflow state.  Anybody know if it is possible and how it is done?

Thanks.

Comment: Please include in your question: the ways you have tried to find an answer before asking on stackoverflow

Comment: Sorry about that I am really groping in the dark as I am not familiar with Plone's API. More Googling pointed me to this code {{ here.portal_workflow.getInfoFor(here, 'review_state') }} I just replaced here with context and it worked.  However, I got the id of the state instead of the title. Anyone know how to get the review state title instead of the id?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can, it is possible, and one way is to use the **portal_workflow** tool e.g. from `parts/omelette/plone/app/contentrules/tests/test_action_workflow.py`:

```
 self.assertEquals('published', 
     self.portal.portal_workflow.getInfoFor(self.folder.d1, 'review_state'))
```

More generally, something like:

```
context.portal_workflow.getInfoFor(context, 'review_state')
```

in a page template should work. Or use the **portal_catalog** as Spanky suggests e.g. if "obj" is a catalog "brain" (i.e. part of a result set from a catalog search) then:

```
obj.review_state
```

should work.

Comment: Thanks aclark. This is exactly the same as what I found and mentioned above. I used {{ context.portal_workflow.getInfoFor(context, 'review_state') }} in my templated email.

Answer (score 1):

The portal_catalog also has an index of the workflow's Review State, so if you don't already have the object you're working on (e.g. context ≠ the object) you could use the catalog, look up the object and get the review state from the resulting "brains" object.

Apparently there are ALSO browser view methods available to you as well, and I notice that one of them is workflow_state. See:

http://plone.org/documentation/manual/theme-reference/page/otherinfo

Comment: collective.easytemplate can do a query to the portal catalog but this seems more complicated to me. Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: I missed out that you edited your post.  Yes, browser view methods can also be accessed from collective.easytemplate.  The code to get the workflow state is {{ view("plone_context_state", "workflow_state") }}